# How to use CHGDTA in CL Programming ? (as400)

Tags: ibm-midrange

***please note this is a task for school***

I'm trying to create a CL Program and this is the breakdown of the requirements I've gathered:

- CL program calls DFU program
- a menu with options will pop up

  ```
               - Enter CIF data

               - Edit CIF data

               - Exit
  ```
- When a user selects an option a message will appear stating an action has been taken, example: "CIF Data Entry Program is now executing"

I'm very new to CL programming, and I've attempted various things, and keep coming across the error CPF0001 (Application Error) unmonitored by CIFCL99 (my cl program) at statement 000000050, I have no idea what that means, I've looked it up and got even more confused.

Here is a screen shot of my CL program, I know that `SNDPGMMSG` doesn't do anything as I'm pretty sure I need to set conditions for that message to pop up. But I can't even get the DFU program to launch. I don't even know if my syntax is wrong, I'm not declaring any variables, so I wouldn't need to right? I've looked at dozens of examples and tried to make something of it.

[image: CIF CL PROGRAM]

here is the structure of the library. Inside QCLSRC is the source code for the CLLE program CIFCL99, and inside of QDDSSRC is the source code for CIFFILE and CIFFILE1

[image: STRUCTURE]

thank you for your time.

Comment: The requirement to "call the DFU program" is effected by the DFU Program (DFUPGM) parameter specification on the Change Data (CHGDTA) command statement; i.e. remove the 'CALL PGM(CIF)' entirely, because calling the DFU program directly is not the proper way to invoke the DFU program, the 'CHGDTA DFUPGM(CIF)' is the proper way to invoke the DFU program.

Comment: The school assignment probably expects that a Display File (DSPF) will be created on which the options (Enter data, Edit Data, Exit) would appear; that would be separate from the DFU Display file providing for date entry\update; see SNDRCVF. I am unaware however, of an ability of the DFU Change Data feature to provide either an insert-only or an update-only capability. The messaging is also tricky, if not either disruptive [delayed by some constant amount of time or until user intervention such as press enter to continue... and that would be odd] or so temporal as likely never to be noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: Screen shots are not only overkill, they also prevent copying source statements from **text** version of the description into the text-based 5250 screen, or for use of copy\paste into a followup reply, and prevent searching on the potentially relevant *text* to find a similar issue; a total PITA IMO.

Anyhow, the problem seems likely to be that the *file* specified on the Change Data (CHGDTA) is not the **expected** file type; the file named CIF is presumably the **Device File** [attribute **DFU**] instead of a **Database File** which is either of the files: CIFFILE [attribute PF-DTA] or CIFFILE1 [attribute LF-DTA; though PDM omits the *DTA, as if an LF can not have *SRC attribute, but they apparently did not know any better ;-)

As for the msg CPF0001, the origin is easily determined.  When that message appears, press F1=Help [with the cursor positioned on the message text "Error found on &1 command." and then press F10=Display Messages In Job Log to see what was the preceding error messages in the joblog.  For the message(s) that appear **after** the request [i.e. the CALL invocation] and before the "Error found...", again press F1=Help on each, and read the Problem and Cause text. **[edit]** correction to name the CALL statement command as the problem identified by the error on statement 50 which almost surely corresponds to line 00005.00, and would be visible in the compiler listing produced by the CRTCLPGM [or CRTBNDCL].**[/edit]**

Comment: This is amazing and super informative thank you so much, i'm not at a computer that has access to as400 right now but as soon as im done work I'll get right on it. Just a quick question, you mentioned the Display File, is that something I can create within CL, or I can only do that through SDA and then that also needs to get called from the CL program?

Comment: I removed the `CALL PGM(CIF)` line, and now it compiles and i can run it but nothing happens it just stays on the same screen. The program doesn't come up. I've tried replacing CIF with CIFFILE and CIFFILE1 but so far nothing happened. Do I need additional values to run CHGDTA? or additional commands so that the DFU program comes up?

Comment: The DSPF object is created from source; the Screen Design Aid (SDA) is just an interactive utility to assist in generating the Data Description Specifications (DDS) source and the DSPF. The Create Display File (CRTDSPF) command creates the file from a named Source Member (SRCMBR) and Source File (SRCFILE) irrespective the origin of the DDS source. The Send/Receive File (SNDRCVF) is the run-time request to ask the CL program to open\present the display file and interact with the user for input (receive) and output (send).

Comment: Regarding the presumed-to-be corrected CHGDTA invocation "stays on the same screen", there is an unfortunate issue with that feature, a defect really, whereby the failing invocation **does not issue an Escape message**. Ugh. So unlike the prior issue with CPF0001 Escape msg [per the msg CPD0172 "Parameters passed on CALL do not match those required." when the CALL failed, a failing CHGDTA request likely just _falls through_ to the next statement in the CLP :-( Press the F10=Include Detailed Messages or issue Display Job Log (DSPJOBLOG) to review the errors logged following the CHGDTA request.

Comment: CRPence, you have been truly outstanding thank you so much for help. Once I looked through the DSPJOBLOG it became clear, I simply wasn't stating where the DFU program was lol, and now I have it running perfectly with a message stating that the program is executing. I figured out that I'll be using the SDA to add each program to the menu and from there it'll just say that the program is about to run, at least I'm hoping that's what the professor meant lol. Either way I'm finally one step closer to completing this task. thank you again!